# ElasticSearch.net Array of Attachment Search is returning all attachments with search results how to retrieve only hits

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, attachment, elasticsearch.net

```
Class Mail
{
  public string MailID               {get;set;}

  [nested]
  public List<Attachment> attachments {get;set;}

}
Class Attachment
{
  public int AttachmentID {get;set;}

  public string Data {get; set;}   

  [nested]
  public Nest.attachment {get;set;}

}
```

Above is my indexing Structure with the Ingest-Pipeline data is indexed properly but when try to search on attachment  content it returns hole attachment object with all attachments along with the actual search attachments.
in Result I want only attachments with searched result

following is my Query

```
                var response1 = elasticClient.Search<Mail>(s => s
                                          .Index(indexName)
                                          .Query(q =>
                                           q.Match(mq => mq.Field("attachments.attachment.content").Query("b"))
                                           ));
```

Comment: In mapping what is type of attachments nested or object?

Comment: its a Nested Object

Answer (score 0):

Since attachments is a nested field you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-query-usage.html)

```
.Nested(c => c
    .Path(p => p.attachments)
    .InnerHits = new InnerHits {},
    .Query(q =>
           q.Match(mq => mq.Field("attachments.attachment.content").Query("b"))
))
```

In response you  need to read object from inner hits

Comment: Since both attachments and  attachment are of nested type , did you try nesting till second level ex q.Nested(n =>
               n.Path("attachments")
                 .Query(q2=> q2.Nested(
                     n2 => n2.Path("attachments.attachment")
                        .Query(q3 =>